# Flatmap my observable to subject

Tags: rx-java2

The question is a little tricky.

I am trying to implement the observable interface, within it i need to start listen to another publicsubject once the observable meet some circustance, so i write some code like this:

```
public myAPI(){
   return  restAPI.call()
                .flatmap{ ret ->
                   if(ret == success) return myPublishSubject
                 }
```

can it guarantee the subscribe start subscribe to the publishsubject only after restAPI call is done successfully ?

Answer (score 1):

The `flatMap`'s `Function` callback is invoked when there is a value from upstream, in this case, the `restAPI.call()`.

However, note that mapping to a `PublishSubject` late can result in items being missed. To avoid such problems, you can consider using `BehaviorSubject` that retains the last item it received so the `flatMap` can emit immediately upon subscribing to it.

In addition, repeatedly mapping to the same `Subject` can result in memory leaks and item duplication. Unfortunately, you'd have to complete the `Subject` in order to release it, but then it becomes unusable for dispatching further events. `takeUntil` may help in this case though.

Comment: What is leaking if it always return same subject ?

Comment: Subscriptions to the Subject keeps growing and nobody unsubscribes.